# Matlab Data cursor tip when hovering

Tags: matlab

Data cursor tips in matlab are immensely useful, but as far as I know you have to always click on the plot to apply them.

Is it possible to set it up so that they temporarily appear when you hover the mouse cursor over a data point, then dissappear when you move the mouse away? The reason I ask is that I often want to know the xyz of a point but don't want to add a data tip permanently

Comment: You realize that with a right-click, you can remove the data tip again, and that you can move the data tip around? If you want to add a hover-tip, you'd probably need to modify the figure's WindowButtonMotionFcn

Comment: Hi Jonas thanks for your reply. I knew you could remove them, but I'd really like to have a hover style data tip. Will look at WindowButtonMotionFcn

Comment: You could look at the code for e.g. `impoint`, where they have the cursor change as you hover over the object for inspiration.

Comment: I'll check that one out too! Thanks